# How to filter objects from a QuerySet in list

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to use the [django-friendship](https://github.com/revsys/django-friendship) package in order to get the Friend requests to my user. When I use: `Friend.objects.requests(user=request.user)` it returns a list of id's of users who sent a request to `request.user` in a form such as:

`[<FriendshipRequest: 14>, <FriendshipRequest: 15>, <FriendshipRequest: 16>, <FriendshipRequest: 18>]` which is a list of the quesryset of FriendshipRequest objects to `request.user`

I plan on using `id__in` in order to retrieve users who sent a friend request to my user, however, I cannot use that because I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <FriendshipRequest: 14>.
```

This is my complete code:

```
requests = Friend.objects.requests(user=request.user)
friend_requests = Profile.objects.filter(id__in=requests)
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It does not seem to make much sense. Normally the `id` of the `Profile` is not the same as the one of the `Friend`s (in this case).

Comment: when looking at the `models.py` In django-friendship to_user ad from_user have Foreign key relationship with AUTH_USER. So I believe the profile id will be the same